# How to get "coverage on new code" displayed on the SonarQube dashboard?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 5.6 for analysing c# legacy application code. I'm able to see data for latest check-in in terms of added LOC, new defects, added technical debt etc. But the "coverage on new code" section shows nothing but dash. I'm using SVN Source control.

How can I enable the "coverage on new code" metric?                       I'm using dotcover.exe to create coverage.html and this HTML report is getting sent to SonarQube via additional parameters in TeamCity build step.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details on how you have tried to pass your coverage reports into the analysis.

Comment: Added details above...

Answer (score -1):

I´m using git and jacoco for coverage. after activating the SCM in the admin area, I got "coverage on new code"

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but my configuration is .Net specific. I'm using SVN as source control and dotcover to generate coverage report which is getting loaded in Sonar via TeamCity.